# mongoose findByIdAndDelete

Tags: express, mongoose

so I'm learning my way to build my first project and I tried to use the `findByIdAndDelete` but can't make it work when I test it in postman.

```js
const express = require("express");
const Appointment = require("../models/Appointment");

const router = express.Router();

router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  Appointment.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Appointment.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm aware if I have a noobie mistakes but would lovesome help:)

Comment: The http verb for first route must be a get.  Change `router.delete('/'` to `router.get('/'`.
And now you can re try your delete